# Newton's Third Law Equal and Opposite Force to Centripetal Force

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm swirling a mass on a string around my head.  We know there is a centripetal force, which is center acting.  Since Newton's Third Law says that all forces come in pairs, what is the equal and opposite force to the center-seeking force?

Comment: The string pulls the mass in. The opposite force is the mass pulling the string out.

Comment: A common confusion is that there must be some equal and opposite force on the _mass_. That's not true. There's no force balancing the force of the string on the mass, that's why the mass goes in a circle instead of a straight line.

Comment: knzhou's comments are correct.

Answer (score 2):

That is a force on your hand, which swirls the object around.

There are only two forces present here on the object: gravity and string tension. And your hand causes the string tension so it feels the string tension as well but in the opposite direction. A part of the string tension pulls inwards, and takes the role as the centripetal force, and this pull is felt in your hand according to Newton's 3rd law.